# Why cant I upload to an existing Azure container?

Tags: c#, azure

I am new to working with azure via C# and I am looking to upload an existing file to an existing azure storage container. I am currently able to create a new local file and then upload it to a container that I create as seen in the CreateContainerAndUploadFile method. However when I try to upload an existing file to an existing container it does not work. When using the CreateContainerAndUploadFile method I see the new container and .txt file appear, but the UploadFile method runs all the way through with no errors and I do not see the file appear in the container.

If anyone knows why the method is running through but not uploading I would greatly appreciate the help.

```
public class Launcher
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlobManager manager = new BlobManager();

        manager.UploadFile("DemoText.txt", "democontainer");

        manager.CreateContainerAndUploadFile("demo");
    }
}



public class BlobManager
    {
        private BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;

        public BlobManager()
    {
        try
        {
            // Get azure table storage connection string.
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StorageConnectionString");
            blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {
            throw ExceptionObj;
        }
    }

    public void UploadFile(string fileName, string container)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering Upload to existing blob");
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
        containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Existing blob obtained");


        string localPath = "./";
        string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Local file path set");

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob;
        //// Create a block blob
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine($"BlobClient established with filename {fileName}");

        //// Open the file and upload its data

        using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
        blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
        uploadFileStream.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Uploaded File to existing container");
    }


    public void CreateContainerAndUploadFile(string containerName)
    {

        //Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient =
            new BlobServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StorageConnectionString"));
        Console.WriteLine("Pre-container");

        // Create the container and return a container client object
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainer(containerName + Guid.NewGuid());

        Console.WriteLine("Post-container");

        // Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
        string localPath = "./";
        string fileName = "demo" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
        string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

        // Write text to the file
        File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Hello, World!");

        // Get a reference to the blob
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

        Console.WriteLine($"Uploading to Blob storage as blob: {fileName}");
        //// Open the file and upload its data
        using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
        blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
        uploadFileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please change the following line of code `blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);` to `blobClient.Upload(uploadFileStream, true);`.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks for the help!

Comment: You seem to be mixing up quite a bit of async code with synchronous code, [read up on asynchronous programming in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) to get a better understanding why your code does not work

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not able to upload the blob is because you're calling an `async` function but not waiting for it to complete.

Considering your calling method is `sync` and not `async`, I would recommend changing the following line of code:

```
blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
```

to

```
blobClient.Upload(uploadFileStream, true);
```

Other alternative would be to convert the wrapper method as async methods and await the completion of all async methods.